# Setting Up CPLEX in Eclipse C++ on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, cplex

I have installed CPLEX 12.6.3 (CPLEX_Studio_Community1263) and I want to integrate CPLEX in my Eclipse C++ project (on Linux). But I don't know which steps I have to follow to include CPLEX in my project.

Even by following exactly the steps shown [at this link](https://notesblogblog.wordpress.com/2012/08/25/setting-up-cplex-for-academics-with-eclipse-on-linux/), it still not working for me (I can't import `cpelx.jar` in my project). The path of my  `cplex.jar` is

```
/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1263/cplex/lib/cpelx.jar
```

When I right-click on my project and go to

```
Properties --> Settings --> GCC C++ Linker --> Libraries
```

to add the `cplex.jar` in my project, it is impossible to add the .jar because I can't select it (it is deselected and impossible to select it).

Can some one explain me how I can include CPLEX in my project?

Comment: I'm confused ... why are you trying to use a Java jar file from a C++ program?

Comment: @rkersh  simply, I want to use CPLEX in my C ++ project but I do not know how to integrate it !! I want to know what I have to do to include CPLEX in my C++ Project

Answer (score 0):

The link you reference is for setting up a Java program.  This will not help you.

Instead, you should try running one of the C++ examples shipped with CPLEX.  Try the following (assuming your path is correct from above):

```
$ cd /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1263/cplex/examples/x86-64_linux/static_pic
$ make ilolpex1 2>&1 | tee output.txt
```

This will save the output in `output.txt` so that you can look at it later. It should give you an idea of what the required command line arguments are.

For example, on my system (x86-64_linux), I see this in the output:

```
$ make ilolpex1
g++ -O0 -c -m64 -O -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -fexceptions -DNDEBUG -DIL_STD -I../../../include -I../../../../concert/include  ../../../examples/src/cpp/ilolpex1.cpp -o ilolpex1.o
g++ -O0 -m64 -O -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -fexceptions -DNDEBUG -DIL_STD -I../../../include -I../../../../concert/include  -L../../../lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic -L../../../../concert/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic -o ilolpex1 ilolpex1.o -lconcert -lilocplex -lcplex -lm -lpthread
```

This tells you everything you need to know to compile and link your program.  You'll just need to figure out where to enter this information in Eclipse.